# How can I insert an image below any texts above any backgrounds?

Tags: html, css

I designed a (vue) component that produces an SVG intended to replace, everywhere on the site, the text selection style.

This SVG is the same size as the body and has one or more bubble-like filled paths around the selections.

There appear to be no simple solution for a given SVG/image to lay ABOVE **any** background and BELOW **any** texts. Am I wrong ?

If so, what could be a *non-intrusive* workaround (i.e. not to have to add something to every component, or otherwise, the minimal systematic addition compatible with most imaginable component's style) ?

- I tried wrapping all text elements with their own overlaid SVG component but the code became unreadable and hardly maintabable
- I tried using mask-image but frankly I'm helpless at this point

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise to provide a simple HTML/CSS demo of the problem using the editor.